# Materializecss date picker is not working

Tags: datepicker, materialize

I am using CDN and no jQuery. Its just 1 index file everything is CDN.
Nothing happens when i click on my the date picker.
My index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" class="datepicker">

    <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
            var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The console should be your first port of call, always. If you had checked you would have seen this message:

Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

This is misleading documentation but easily fixable by either declaring options or removing it from the init function, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem copy+pasting from materialize's page, I removed 'options' and the datepicker popped right up after a hard refresh.

```
 var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems);
```

Answer (score 0):

@River is correct - the problem here is the options object, which is referenced but undeclared. Here is the instruction from the docs:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });
```

https://materializecss.com/pickers.html

The options object (key:value pairs) is not required unless you are initializing the component with some options - for instance, to increase the date range from 10 to 20 years. So you can either remove the options object:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems);
  });
```

Or declare your options:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var options = {'yearRange':20}
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);
  });
```

I have requested a change to the docs but as yet it hasn't been picked up by the devs. The Gitter channel is full of people asking why such and such component doesn't work when they've used the exact code from the docs.

Answer (score -1):

You have to provide the options by yourself like `M.Datepicker.init(elems, {autoClose:true});`  for example